Flask api error; An error occurred: 415 Unsupported Media Type: - Content-Type was not 'application/json'
So I'm working on a project with my mate and we have encountered a problem. I have a variable in JavaScript and i need it in python so i made a flask and a post request but it hits me with an error when i run it. I have tried looking other places and tried other solutions but none of them seem to work, can anyone see my error?
Python:
@app.route('/receive-data', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    data = request.get_json()  # Use request.get_json() to explicitly parse JSON
    if data is None:
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid content type or empty payload"}), 400

    variable = data.get('variable')
    print(f"Received variable from JavaScript: {variable}")
    return jsonify({"status": "success", "received_variable": variable})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Javascript:

              var audioControls = document.getElementById("audioControls");

              let currentSong = null
              let audioElement = document.getElementById("audio");
             audioElement.src = currentSong
              let beatcheckbox = false
              let clonecheckbox = false

             document.getElementById("beatcb").addEventListener("change", function() {
      var bcheckbox = document.getElementById("beatcb");
      

            // Check if the checkbox is checked
            if (bcheckbox.checked) {
              console.log("beat checkbox is checked");
              beatcheckbox = true
              // The variable you want to send to Python
              const myVariable = beatcheckbox;

              // Send the variable using fetch
              fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/receive-data', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ variable: myVariable })
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                return response.text().then(text => { throw new Error(text) });
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Response from server:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
            } else {
              console.log("beat checkbox is not checked");
              beatcheckbox = false
            }
          });


    document.getElementById("clonecb").addEventListener("change", function() {

      var clonecbox = document.getElementById("clonecb");

     

    if (clonecbox.checked) {
        console.log("clone checkbox is checked");
        clonecheckbox = true
      } else {
        console.log("clone checkbox is not checked");
        clonecheckbox = false
      }
    });

             

I have tried adding accept to the headers (which didn't work), looking in postman, in postman i saw that the accept header wasn't set and the Content-Type was set to text/html. I have looked through all my code and the only point that the receive data is being mentioned is in the code i have given.
I have tried adding force=true but it now creates this problem: An error occurred: 400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

try to hitflask end point from postman client with all the request data and see

try request.get_json(force=True)

Hi Johnny i tried your solution but now i get this error:
An error occurred: 400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

You need to allow your Flask backend to respond to requests from the frontend by adding CORS headers to the server's responses.
You have to update your Python code to the following:


from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/receive-data', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    data = request.get_json()  # Use request.get_json() to explicitly parse JSON
    if data is None:
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid content type or empty payload"}), 400

    variable = data.get('variable')
    print(f"Received variable from JavaScript: {variable}")
    return jsonify({"status": "success", "received_variable": variable})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)



Let me know if this works
